# Spark Cassandra Connector in windows OS

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Is there any link that how to integrate Spark & Cassandra using Spark cassandra connector in windows 7 64 bit  OS, i have referred so many websites where every websites are integrating only in Linux based OS.

Regards,
Mohan Raj

Comment: Please use google or search on site, StacOverflow is not a search engine